# Passing a variable from ReactJS frontend to NodeJS back end using a GET route

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, reactjs

I am working on a react app and am trying to find a way to pass a variable I define in my front-end (Question.js) to my back-end (server.js) so that I can issue different queries. I have the code

```
//Question.js

state = {
        data: null
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.callBackendAPI()
            .then(res => this.setState({ data: res.express }))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }

    callBackendAPI = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('/express_backend');
        const body = await response.json();

        if (response.status !== 200) {
            throw Error(body.message)
        }
        return body;
    };
```

```
//server.js

con.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    con.query("SELECT question FROM s1questions WHERE ID = 1", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        app.get('/express_backend', (req, res) => {
            var x = JSON.stringify(result[0].question);
            res.send({ express: `${x}` });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Your route handler probably shouldn't be defined within your database connection callback
Also, what is the database package that you're using? You'll want to use parameterized queries in order to retrieve your questions

Answer (score 1):

Your sever should probably split your database connection from your route handler definitions. Also, you could use query parameters to access questions based on their id in the database.

```js
// question.js
    callBackendAPI = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`/express_backend?questionId=1`);
        const body = await response.json();

        if (response.status !== 200) {
            throw Error(body.message)
        }
        return body;
    };
```

```js
// server.js
app.get('/express_backend', (req, res) => {
  const { questionId } = req.query;

  // query database for question by id
});
```

Comment: @coldcav Please accept the answer if you find it helpful.